# Git Bash executa NPM no Prompt do Windows

Tags: git, prompt

Estou usando o **Git Bash** para rodar meu projeto desenvolvido com **React**.

Depois que comecei a usar o **Windows 10**, ao digitar o comando `npm run dev` uma nova janela de Prompt do Windows é aberta para a executação do comando, *antes*, *o mesmo comando era executado dentro do próprio Git Bash*.

Já procurei como configurar para que o comando continue no GitBash e não estou achando uma solução!

Alguém sabe alguma solução?

Comment: Vc usa VS Code? Já tentou rodar o comando pelo terminal do próprio VS?

Comment: Sim, já tentei e acontece a mesma coisa, ele abre uma janela de prompt. Estou procurando uma forma de resolver no VS Code, ate acho que seria mais interessante rodar por la mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o [Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), ou qualquer outra distro Linux, disponível na Microsoft Store, ao invés do Bash que vem com a instalação do Git para Windows.

Com isso você terá o verdadeiro Bash rodando no [Subsistema Windows para Linux](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsistema_Windows_para_Linux). A vantagem é que você terá os mesmos comportamentos e customizações do Bash, integrado com o Windows, atualmente é possível abrir o Code, por exemplo, a partir do Bash com o seguinte comando:

```
code .
```

Então provavelmente você terá o comportamento que estava acostumado, ou será mais fácil configurar para voltar a ter.

O WSL2 já está sendo desenvolvido, [leia mais](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/).

Comment: Esse apontamento acontece aqui onde trabalho, infelizmente tem que ser Windows. Tem sido um desafio resolver esse problema, pois funcionava normal.